# Passing Parameters to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Any ideas on how to pass parameters to Silverlight on startup from URL QueryString?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you can take is to expose a method that can be accessed from JavaScript. So in your xaml.cs file you need to add the following to your constructor:

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
```

Then add the following event handler:

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("YourControlName", this);
}
```

and:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public void YourMethod(string yourData)
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Then in the ascx or aspx page where your Silverlight control is instantiated add the following JavaScript:

```
var silverlightControl;

function onSilverlightLoad(sender, args) {
    silverlightControl = sender.getHost();
    var yourData = "some data";
    silverlightControl.Content.YourControlName.YourMethod(yourData);
}
```

It does also mean that your Silverlight control has to be instantiated via the `<object...` tag rather than via `<asp:Silverlight...`

Comment: I have multiple SL clients on the page, will this JS pass the data to all the clients?
thanks

Comment: @Jayesh - each Silverlight client instantiated can have it's own onLoad handler so you can call different methods on startup.

Answer (score 2):

Although Chris's method will work, it's easier to pass startup information through Silverlight's [initialization parameters feature](http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/How-to-pass-initialize-parameters-to-Silverlight-application-using-ASP.NET-3.5-Silverlight-control.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is get at key-value pairs of the query string, there is a much simpler way using the [HtmlPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage(VS.95).aspx) class:

```
HtmlPage.Document.QueryString["your_key"];
```